Generating line parallel to polyline scheme using ArcGIS Pro
I am working on a forest edge map.
What I currently have is a polyline that describe each forest patch (each segment is different based on its exposition) and a soil map (soil map underneath).

I would like to characterize again each segment, intersect based on the outside and inside soil occupation. As only using the intercept between the lines and the occupation map could be misleading (the soil occupation could be the same one meter away from the line an then different).
I would like to create a line that would follow the shape of my polylines 8 meters away on the "outside" and on the "inside", intersect the line with the soil occupation map [1.], and create a buffer on the intersects that would split the main "segment" in sub-parts that would be described with the following typology [2.] :
example :

Exposition : South
Intern environnement : Grassland
External environnement : Broadleave forest

(Here is one sketch of what it should look like)

Parallel line to segment split by soil occupation (only inner for the exemple) :


Buffer on the lines to split the soil occupation by exposition and soil occupation (only inner for the exemple) :



My current strategy was to :
-Create a 8 m outside and inside buffer
-Polygon to line
-Feature to vertices
-Point to line
Yet the result is quiet odd and I am not sure this is the best way to do it ...

What would you recommend me to try to divide my segments based on the outer (+7.5m) and inner (-7.5m) soil occupation?
